# Pyomo: constraint with if clause to check indexes

Tags: pyomo

As a case study for school I'm using PYOMO as an optimizer.

```
# Set T: example: [0,1,2,3,4]
model.T = pyo.Set(initialize=list(df2.columns))

# Set TT: example: [0,1,2,3,4]
model.TT = pyo.Set(initialize=list(df2.columns))

# Set P: example: [A,B,C,D]
model.P = pyo.Set(initialize=list(df.iloc[:,0]))

# Set Q: example: [q1,q2,q3]
model.Q = pyo.Set(initialize=range(0,df3.shape[1]))

# Demand for product p at time t
model.d = pyo.Param(model.P,model.T,initialize=demand,domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)

# Quantity q for product p and part of the possible quantities Q
model.q = pyo.Param(model.P,model.Q,initialize=quantities,domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)

# Decision variable: 1, if we decide to produce quantity q for product p in the timeperiod [t,tt] 
model.X = pyo.Var(model.T,model.TT,model.P,model.Q,domain=pyo.Binary)

# Inventory at time t of product p
model.I = pyo.Var(model.T,model.P,domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)
```

In constraint 4 I want to make sure that the index model.T <= model.TT. The following is what I do now. Is this correct or are there other better solutions?

```
def con_4(m,i,j,k):
    if i > j:
        return pyo.Expression.Skip
    else:
        return sum(m.X[i,j,k,l] <= 1 for l in m.Q)
model.con4 = pyo.Constraint(model.T, model.TT, model.P, rule=con_4)
```

Further, I have constraint 2, again trying to include T<=TT:

I_{tp} = I_{(t−1)p} − d_{tp} + ∑ _{t∗∈T:t∗≤t} ∑ *{q∈Qp} ( q * X*{t∗tpq} )       ∀t∈T,∀p∈P

```
def con_2(m,i,j):
    if m.T > m.TT:
        return pyo.Expression.Skip
    else:
        return m.I[i,j] == m.I[i-1,j] - m.d[i,j] + sum(sum(m.q[j,k]*m.X[l,i,j,k] for k in m.Q) for l in m.T)
model.con2 = pyo.Constraint(model.T, model.P, rule=con_2)
```

This seems wrong, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: I don't understand con_2. Can you write it down in standard mathematical notation?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you provided your set definitions with a comment.  (and comment your decision variables)  such as:  `model.T = Set(...)  # time periods`.  It would probably be best if you edit above and paste *all* of your model in that format, and clearly indicate what `X` implies based on the subscripting.

Comment: @AirSquid I added some more info, thanks for answering!

Comment: Note that in con_2 `T` is passed on as `I`. It is better to use meaningful names: that causes less confusion.